# Is there any way to evaluate (expand-file-name) in .dir-locals.el?

Tags: emacs, emacs23

I'm trying to move all my compilation config (`compilation-command` and `compilation-directory` to be exact) to `.dir-locals.el` file at the top of my project. It is working fine except that I can't find the way to use `expand-file-name` there and without it I have to use absolute path, which is not really convenient.

So, is there a way (or a dirty hack) to make local directory variables to evaluate values before assigning?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `eval` "variable" to evaluate an arbitrary elisp expression.  You will probably want to customize `enable-local-eval` and/or `safe-local-eval-forms` so you don't get asked each time.

Comment: I've tried to set `compilation-directory` through `Eval:` but it just does not work for some reason. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833928/how-do-i-set-buffer-local-variable-from-eval-in-dir-local-el