# How do I set buffer local variable from Eval: in .dir-local.el?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs23

Why this works

```
((nil . ((compilation-directory . "/home/vava/code_directory/")
         (compilation-command . "rake"))
))
```

and this doesn't?

```
((nil . ((Eval . (setq compilation-directory "/home/vava/code_directory"))
         (compilation-command . "rake"))
))
```

What I'm doing wrong here?

I have set `enable-local-eval` in .emacs.

Comment: I'm trying to do a similar thing to you...set some variables dynamically when reading a .dir-local.el: its a shame that it doesn't seem to be possible right now.

Answer (score 9):

Emacs Lisp is case-sensitive: try lower-case "eval":

```
((nil . ((eval . (setq compilation-directory "/home/vava/code_directory"))
         (compilation-command . "rake"))))
```

Also, the name of the file for directory-local variables is *.dir-locals.el*, not *.dir-local.el* as in the question headline.

Answer (score -3):

Obviously you're assuming that "eval" has the same special meaning in directory-local variables that it does in file-local variables; and yet the documentation doesn't seem to confirm this.  So my guess is: you simply can't do it.