# Define new variable in .dir-locals.el

Tags: emacs, elisp

I am new to emacs. How do I define and use new variable in .dir-locals.el?

This is my .dir-locals.el and it didn't work.

```
(setq clang_args '("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                   "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))
((c-mode . ((company-clang-arguments . clang_args)
            (flycheck-clang-args . clang_args))))
```

This works

```
((c-mode . ((company-clang-arguments . ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                        "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))
            (flycheck-clang-args . ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                    "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include")))))
```

According to the examples from [How do I set buffer local variable from Eval: in .dir-local.el?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2833928/how-do-i-set-buffer-local-variable-from-eval-in-dir-local-el/4365847#4365847), I tried other methods but fail.

```
((c-mode . ((eval . (setq company-clang-arguments ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                                   "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))
            (eval . (setq flycheck-clang-args ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                               "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))))))
```

and

```
((c-mode . ((eval . (setq clang_args ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                      "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))
            (company-clang-arguments . clang_args)
            (flycheck-clang-args . clang_args))))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the special keyword `eval` to execute arbitrary lisp code, such as e.g., defining a temporary variable. However, you then cannot use that variable in subsequent alist-style variable declarations. That is, the following doesn't work:

```lisp
((c-mode . ((eval . (setq clang-args ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                      "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))
            (company-clang-arguments . clang-args)
            (flycheck-clang-args . clang-args))))
```

because while setting `clang-args` succeeds in the `setq` form, the two variable definitions below assign the *symbol* `clang-args` to `company-clang-arguments` and `flycheck-clang-args` respectively, not the value of the *variable* `clang-args` previously defined.
There are two options that do work, though:

1) Using the same string literals twice:

```lisp
((c-mode . ((company-clang-arguments . ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                        "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include"))
            (flycheck-clang-args . ("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                    "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include")))))
```

2) Doing the actual variable assignment also inside the `eval` form:

```lisp
((c-mode . ((eval . (let ((clang-args '("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                        "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include")))
                      (setq company-clang-arguments clang-args
                            flycheck-clang-args clang-args))))))
```

The first one is more readable in my opinion while the second one is perhaps more maintainable because changes to the values only have to be made in one location.

---

**Addendum:** note the comment below by `phils`: his suggestion is to replace `set` with `setq-local` in the second option. This would result in the following:

```lisp
((c-mode . ((eval . (let ((clang-args '("-isystem/usr/include/glib-2.0"
                                        "-isystem/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include")))
                      (setq-local company-clang-arguments clang-args
                                  flycheck-clang-args clang-args))))))
```

Comment: In general be wary of what you are `setq`ing via `eval` in this way. Unless the variable is already (or automatically) buffer-local, then `setq` will set the global value (as normal), so examples (1) and (2) are not necessarily equivalent. Recent versions of Emacs provide `setq-local` (which is more convenient than the older method for setting a buffer-local value when the variable is not already/automatically so), and I would be inclined to use it in such situations regardless, for better clarity.

Answer (score 7):

While `setq` is the right command to set variables in elisp code, `.dir-locals.el` is a special file that requires variable definitions in a certain format.

To use variables in your settings, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4365847/261142) to a related question.

From the [GNU Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Directory-Variables.html):

The `.dir-locals.el` file should hold a specially-constructed list, which maps major mode names (symbols) to alists (see [Association Lists](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Association-Lists.html#Association-Lists) in The Emacs Lisp Reference Manual). Each alist entry consists of a variable name and the directory-local value to assign to that variable, when the specified major mode is enabled. Instead of a mode name, you can specify `nil`, which means that the alist applies to any mode; or you can specify a subdirectory name (a string), in which case the alist applies to all files in that subdirectory.

Here’s an example of a `.dir-locals.el` file:

```lisp
((nil . ((indent-tabs-mode . t)
         (fill-column . 80)))
 (c-mode . ((c-file-style . "BSD")
            (subdirs . nil)))
 ("src/imported"
  . ((nil . ((change-log-default-name
              . "ChangeLog.local"))))))
```

This sets `indent-tabs-mode` and fill-column for any file in the directory tree, and the indentation style for any C source file. The special subdirs element is not a variable, but a special keyword which indicates that the C mode settings are only to be applied in the current directory, not in any subdirectories. Finally, it specifies a different ChangeLog file name for any file in the src/imported subdirectory.

Instead of editing the `.dir-locals.el` file by hand, you can use the command <kbd>M-x add-dir-local-variable</kbd>. This prompts for a mode or subdirectory name, and for variable and value, and adds the entry defining the directory-local variable. <kbd>M-x delete-dir-local-variable</kbd> deletes an entry. <kbd>M-x copy-file-locals-to-dir-locals</kbd> copies the file-local variables in the current file into `.dir-locals.el`.

Comment: Thank you. In my case, company-clang-arguments and flycheck-clang-args have same the value, i want to create a new variable for this but how?

Comment: I added a link to a related question that deals with using variables in `.dir-locals.el`.